# How can I use another classes variables in a java class?

Tags: java, swing, class

Ok so I'm trying to get familier with Java, and I've made a simple thing where if you click a button then some text appears. How can I make it so the button and label are created in one class file, and put the code for when the button is clicked in another? Sorry if it sounds like a silly question.

Pastebin code:

```
package com.nate.derp;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Derp {

    private JFrame frmHello;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Derp window = new Derp();
                    window.frmHello.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public Derp() {
        initialize();
    }


    public void initialize() {
        frmHello = new JFrame();

        frmHello.setTitle("Hello");
        frmHello.setBounds(100, 100, 225, 160);
        frmHello.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHello.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final JLabel helloLabel = new JLabel("Hello World!");
        helloLabel.setVisible(false);
        helloLabel.setBounds(40, 89, 145, 16);
        frmHello.getContentPane().add(helloLabel);

        final JButton btnClickMe = new JButton("Click Me!");
        btnClickMe.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                helloLabel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


        btnClickMe.setBounds(54, 29, 117, 29);
        frmHello.getContentPane().add(btnClickMe);


    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you have done so far, we'll help you re-organize it

Comment: A question about OOP design does not really make sense without the context of what each component/class is doing and how they are related.  There are multiple ways to accomplish this (i.e., `static` class, component pattern, event handler pattern) and they are all relevant in certain situations.

Comment: I kept getting formatting errors when I tried to post it here so I hope that if I put it on pastebin that's fine (http://pastebin.com/K5Ad5XH6)

Comment: @Natatos I added your pastebin code to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a JButton and adding an ActionListener, which can be implemented by another class.

So you first create the JButton:

```
Jbutton button = new JButton("hello");
```

Then add the Actionlistener:

```
button.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

Where MyListener is your implementation class

```
class MyListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       ...
    }
}
```